# asp.net application does not auto-start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8.5, autostart

I'm trying to achieve the following for my asp.net MVC application hosted in IIS 8.5:

- When the server boots, the application must be started automatically
- The application must not be terminated due to inactivity
- The application must be restarted once a day at a specified hour

Here is my current configuration in IIS:

- App pool:

  - Start Mode = AlwaysRunning
  - Idle Time-out = 0
  - Disable overlapped recycle = True (doesn't work with "False" either)
  - Recycling / Specific Times = 03:00:00
- Site:

  - Preload Enabled = True

My problem is that the application is shut down just fine at the specified hour (I make tests by adding another entry a few minutes in the future), but it doesn't restart after that, which I verified both in the log (Application_Start doesn't run) and with the long start time for the first request (around 15s while subsequent requests are around 0.07s).

Am I doing something wrong, or is IIS just unable to auto-start my application?

Comment: What version of ASP.Net are you running? The settings you've configured should work fine to start up the app after a recycle: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Comment: @TomJohn I'm using .net framework 4.6.1 with asp.net MVC 5.2.3. I saw the blog you reference after posting the question, and I confirm that it does *not* work, unless you actually add the "PreWarmCache" class and do what it takes to awake the web application in there. So the post seems incomplete to me, it's *not* running Application_Start out-of-the-box (but tell me if I'm doing something wrong!) I'm currently experimenting with, it seems to work if you add a bit more code, but I'm trying to find the cleanest way to do it before posting an answer.

Comment: I've also tried with https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit to execute code when my application DLL is loaded ; it turns out the code *is* executed, but *not* until I send the first request to the web application. So it's a dead end. It's still interesting as it proves that despite the IIS configuration that would make you think it's supposed to do *something*, it's actually not even loading your DLL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying with various settings, it turns out IIS won't ever load your application DLL until the first request, unless you give it a `serviceAutoStartProvider` class, as explained in https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

You must configure IIS like this:

- App pool:

  - Start Mode = AlwaysRunning
  - Idle Time-out = 0
  - Disable overlapped recycle = True (not required if your application allows multiple concurrent instances)
  - Recycling / Specific Times = 03:00:00 (this is just an example, it will restart the application every day at the specified hour)

You also need to edit file `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` (only the relevant parts are shown here):

```
<configuration>
  <system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
      <site name="your site name" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application [...] serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="WarmUp">
        </application>
      </site>
    </sites>

    <serviceAutoStartProviders>
        <add name="WarmUp" type="WarmUp, YourApplicationDLL" />
    </serviceAutoStartProviders> 
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

Then you must add a class in your application DLL:

```
public class WarmUp : System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient
{
    public void Preload(string[] parameters)
    {
        // This is the entry point, but your website is not serving
        // pages yet here, so we can't send requests yet. Instead we
        // start a new thread and return immediately. You could add
        // initialization code that must run before serving any request.
        new Thread(DoWarmUp).Start();
    }

    private static void DoWarmUp()
    {
        // Here we just send a request to the home page to preload it.
        // This will run Application_Start, and compile .cshtml files
        // if you use Razor ; you may want to add more pages to preload
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadData("http://localhost/MyHomePageIWantToPreload");
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it, now your web application is actually ready to serve the home page without any additional delay. If you have specific things in your application you'd like to preload, you may add more initialization code in `DoWarmUp`.

Comment: this is good way to develop specific code for auto start. however the main postulate is **incorrect**. IIS app pool auto-starts de facto without writing any code.. I know because i have done this on IIS 10 and it works..

Comment: @BoppityBop Good to know they improved this for IIS 10 (at last !) However, the OP question was about IIS 8.5, and the article I linked was about IIS 7.5. I'm pretty sure in these versions, IIS wasn't doing anything at all about app pools before the first request came. Could be interesting to know at which version exactly things are changing (so that people can decide to upgrade, or, if not possible, to write custom code).

Comment: i cant prove it simply because there is no iis 8 around. but i am sure it worked with older versions 8.5 included. there are few factors that might influence this which not normally mentioned in the blogs (which usually just steal content from each other).. so i guess you had once of those in your machine setup.. it is all academic really.

Comment: Maybe it started to change in IIS 8, according to this page, this is the version from which the `Application Initialization` module is pre-installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization I can't test this at the moment either, but if I posted that question, something wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe applications/sites IIS are able to restart themselves. I've looked into it several times over the years the most reliable way to achieve this is through scheduled tasks to call a page and keep the site alive.

This is a `script.vbs` file you can call from a scheduled task:

```
Option Explicit
Dim url, xmlhttp

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
url = "http://example.com/page"
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, 0
xmlhttp.send ""

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously this is not an answer I like ;-) But maybe this is indeed the only way. I'll wait a little to see if someone else has a better way, otherwise I'll accept yours in a couple of days.

Comment: No Problem. There are some other potential options, but we've always had a very limited environment (hosting) and those require quite a bit of access to various things on the system.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because it kind of works, even though it will just preload things when the scheduled task runs, so you'll either send too many requests if you update it frequently, or miss application restarts if you send requests too infrequently. Still, it's arguably simpler than my answer when you have access to scheduled tasks. Unless someone comes up with a better way, I'll accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is possible to have Applications Auto-Start.
The part that no-one ever seems to mention is that you have to install "Application Initialization" to get it to work.

Server Manager --> Manage --> Add Roles or features --> Next --> Next --> Next
Expand Web Server (IIS) --> Web Server --> Application Development
And check "Application Initializion"